# How to pass a variable from nextjs to a vanilla js file?

Tags: javascript, next.js

for Canvas Dom operations I included a Vanilla JS file with 'next/script' into my NextJs file. `<Script id="canvasJS" src="/lib/canvas.js" ></Script>` That works fine so far.
Now I need to pass a variable like an ID from the NextJs file to the Vanilla File.
For onClick it works fine with `()=>functionName(value)`, but I have no idea how to pass a value without a user interaction.

It would be cool if someone could tell me how to do that.

thanks in advance
Frank

Comment: Why would you include a vanilla js file? Just use a `useEffect` hook and put all of your logics of canvas in the hook. Docs: `https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect`

Comment: I think it's not possible to write a whole Canvas collaborative whiteboard in a useEffect hook. 

For that reason I only need to get the board ID from the URL and pass it to my vanilla script.

Comment: I tried to fill the value to a hidden input and read the value in the Vanilla JS file, but with that solution I get sometimes a timing problem, that the value is not filled before I read it. 

Currently I need a value from the URL, so I can read it from the vanilla script directly as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach is to read `window.__NEXT_DATA__.props.pageProps` on your vanilla js script. The object is the hydrated props that are coming from server and will be passed to your page component.

But if i were you i will use something like this.

```
import { useLayoutEffect } from 'React';
import Script from 'next/script';

export default function Component() {

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
   // do something you want to do with variable and external script
  },[]);

  return (
    <>
      <Script src="/lib/canvas.js"/>
    </>
  )
}
```

Not entirely sure about what is `canvas.js` does. Probably you could use something like this. The `useLayoutEffect` will run on the browser after DOM mutation, so the code inside `useLayoutEffect` will run after the script is loaded.

For more detail about `next/script` you can read this docs page.
https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script

Comment: window.__NEXT_DATA__.props.pageProps looks really good. With that I can avoid using the the local storage. 

My canvas.js is a complex script for a collaborative whiteboard. It creates sticky notes, text and other forms on a canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my way to do it, is to use local storage.

In my case I check the URL for a board ID in a **getServerSideProps(ctx)** function and if no ID is set I create a unique one.

Then I return the props. In the client side function I pick the bid from the props and write it to local storage:

**Next.js**

```
if (typeof window !== "undefined") 
{
  localStorage.setItem('bid', bid) ;  
}
```

Then in the vanilla JS file I grab the ID by

**Vanilla JS**

```
const bid = localStorage.getItem('bid');
```

Comment: How can you access local storage while still on the server?

Comment: I fill the local storage in the client side part of the page the server side I pick only the pathname for the ID.